# What is the Name of this Style of Coding?

Tags: c#

I can't recall the term I've heard for programming c# like

```
var x= obj.A()
          .B()
          .C()
          .ETC()
```

I see this more and more and I would like to know how to build my code like this.

Answer (score 4):

This style is often called 'fluent'

Some background on this style is http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

There are several good repos on github to see libraries which use this approach - eg fluent validation - https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

Answer (score 2):

This is called [`Fluent interface`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

> A fluent interface is normally implemented by using method chaining to
>   relay the instruction context of a subsequent call (but a fluent
>   interface entails more than just method chaining). Generally, the context is:
>
> - defined through the return value of a called method
> - self-referential, where the new context is equivalent to the last context
> - terminated through the return of a void context.

You can learn a lot of things from the [fluent-interface](/questions/tagged/fluent-interface) tag.